# Extract date from a given string in R

Tags: r, datetime, gsub

Here is a string that I have

```
"7MA_S_VE_MS_FB_MEASURE_P1_2013-08-21_17-42-19.BMP"
```

I am trying to extract dates this way:

```
library(stringr)
as.Date(str_extract(test,"[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}"),"%Y-%m-%d")
```

I am getting **NA** for this.

**Desired output** is

```
2013-08-21
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: in base R, `as.Date(regmatches(tmp, regexpr("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", tmp)))` where tmp is your character vector. You probably just have to replace the "/" with "-" in your regex and it will work.

Comment: @lmo, Thank you it worked

Comment: Use your code but like @lmo said replace "/" with "-".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have replaced your dash `-` with a slash `/` in your regular expression.

```
as.Date(str_extract(string, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2013-08-21"
```

But you can also replace the `[0-9]` bits with `\d`, which represent the same thing. I'm not sure why, but regex pros seem to always use the `\d` version (note that you'll have to escape the backslash with another backslash):

```
as.Date(str_extract(string, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"), format="%Y-%m-%d")
# [1] "2013-08-21"
```

Answer (score 3):

If it as fixed position

```
as.Date(strsplit(str1, "_")[[1]][8])
#[1] "2013-08-21"
```