# Extract date from string in R

Tags: r, string

I have the string

```
string<-c("file_skimmed_2019-12-09.csv")
```

I would like to extract the date from this string. In this case: `2019-12-09`. I used

```
strapplyc(listcsv[1], "[skimmed_.*csv]", simplify = TRUE)
```

but I obtained a wrong result.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46528912/extract-date-from-a-given-string-in-r)?

Comment: Maybe this `sub(".*_(.*).csv", "\\1", string)`?

Comment: Both solutions work! Thank you very much!

Comment: This will match the exact date format that you have: `regmatches(string, regexpr("\\d{4}\\-\\d{2}\\-\\d{2}", string))`

Comment: If you use stringr, you could also try ```sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(string, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}"), "[[", 1)```

Comment: Where does `strapplyc` come from? What's `listcsv[1]`, is that the same as `string`? Make sure the code you post here is consistent and reproducible. Also, try to be more specific than "a wrong result"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Assuming that the reason you want to extract that string is so that you can convert it to `Date` class, remove everything up to and including the underscore and then convert to `Date` class.  This uses the fact that `as.Date` ignores junk characters at the end.  This uses only a simple regular expression and uses no packages.

```
as.Date(sub(".*_", "", string))
## [1] "2019-12-09"
```

**2) strapplyc** To use `strapplyc` as was attempted in the question to get a string result use this code which is likely sufficient:

```
library(gsubfn)

strapplyc(string, "....-..-..", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "2019-12-09"
```

or you can be even more specific with this pattern:

```
strapplyc(string, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", simplify = TRUE)
## [1] "2019-12-09"
```

**3) trimws** Using R 3.6 or later we can use `trimws` to trim away all non-digits from the beginning and end.  This will work as long as there are no digits before or after the date (which is satisfied in the example in the question).  This does not use any packages.

```
trimws(string, whitespace = "\\D")
## [1] "2019-12-09"
```

**4) file_path_sans_ext**  Use the indicated function to remove the extension and then remove everything up to the underscore.  Note that the tools package is included with R so there is nothing to install.  The regular expression is the same simple one used in (1).

```
library(tools)
sub(".*_", "", file_path_sans_ext(string))
## [1] "2019-12-09"
```

**5)** Remove everything before and after the date.  No packages are used.

```
gsub(".*_|.csv$", "", string)
## [1] "2019-12-09"
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
library(stringr)

string<-c("file_skimmed_2019-12-09.csv")

str_extract(string, '[0-9]{4}-[1-2]{2}-[0-9]{2}')
```

I get

```
 [1] "2019-12-09"
```

If you don't know this check regular expressions. Then you can use any `sapply` or `map` functions in order to apply this `str_extract` to each row in your dataset or each element in your list.